# Удалить пустой массив из многомерного массива

Tags: php, массивы

Есть массив такого вида:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [date] => 07.08.2018
            [name] => Название 1
            [desc] => Описание 1.
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [date] => 07.08.2018
            [name] => Название 2
            [desc] => Описание 2.
        )

)
```

Т.е. В массиве массивы в тремя ключами.

Как удалять массивы, в которых не заполнен один или более ключей? Т.е. оставлять только те поля, в которых всё заполнено?

Например, при таких ситуациях:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [date] => 07.08.2018
            [name] => Название 1
            [desc] => Описание 1.
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [date] => 07.08.2018
            [name] => Описание 2
            [desc] => Описание 2.
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [date] => 
            [name] => 
            [desc] => 
        )

)
```

или

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [date] => 07.08.2018
            [name] => Название 1
            [desc] => Описание 1.
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [date] => 07.08.2018
            [name] => Название 2
            [desc] => Описание 2.
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [date] => 
            [name] => Описание 3
            [desc] => 
        )

)
```

Удалить массив с ключом `[2]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$arr = [
    [
        'date' => '07.08.2018',
        'name' => 'Название 1',
        'desc' => 'Описание 1.'
    ],
    [
        'date' => '07.08.2018',
        'name' => 'Название 1',
        'desc' => 'Описание 1.'
    ],
    [
        'date' => '',
        'name' => 'Название 1',
        'desc' => '.'
    ]
];

foreach ($arr as $idx => $subarray) {
    foreach ($subarray as $name => $item) {
        if ($item == null) unset($arr[$idx]);
    }
}

print_r($arr);
```

Comment: Благодарю, отлично). Понимаю, что в основном вопросе этого не было, но все же, а как можно проверить что введено? Т.е. что в строке date действительно дата, а в остальных просто текст (чистить от тегов)? Если что-то не так в одном из массивов, то, например, обрывать цикл и выдавать `die()`?

Comment: @Aaron, то есть сделать проверку на формат даты и на пустоту элементов?

Comment: Да, если пусто - то просто удалить пустые массивы. Если в заполнении ошибки, то не удалять, а именно вернуть ошибку. Что нужно проверять: формат даты (ДД.ММ.ГГГГ) и текстовые поля (тут просто чистить от тегов html, php, js и прочее). Текстовые поля просто чистить и идти дальше. если дата некорректна - останавливать цикл с ошибкой. Как-то так

Comment: @Aaron, [типа такого?](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/bc9eb2db7d657cad4cf876d6cacbb5189982c35a)

Comment: Да, интересный вариант. Чистку полей, видимо, по такому же принципу выполнять надо. А можно не оборачивать в отдельную функцию проверку?

Comment: @Aaron, `if (!(bool) strtotime($subarray['date'])) die (..);`

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$array = array(
   0 => array(
      "date" => "07.08.2018",
      "name" => "Название 1",
      "desc" => "Описание 1"
   ),
   1 => array(
      "date" => "07.08.2018",
      "name" => "Название 2",
      "desc" => "Описание 2"
   ),
   2 => array(
      "date" => "",
      "name" => "Название 3",
      "desc" => ""
   )
);

$array = array_filter($array, function($arr) {
   if (count(array_filter($arr)) == count($arr)) return $arr;
});
print_r($array);
?>
```

Comment: Видели что будет, если у вас будет в подмассиве будет разное количество элементов, не всегда равное 3?

Comment: @Let'ssayPie это в общем, данный же случай частный, то есть по три элемента. Но раз так будет всем спокойней, поправил код.

Answer (score 0):

В добавку примера, от пользователя **user285292**

Например, у нас есть массив в массиве и еще в массиве:

```
<?php
$arr = array(
        array(
            array(
                "text" => '1', "url" => '1'
            )
        ),
        array(
            array(
                "text" => '2', "url" => '2'
            )
        ),
        array(
            array(
                "text" => '3', "url" => '3'
            )
        ),
        array(
            array(
                "text" => 4, "url" => ''
            )
        )
    );

foreach ($arr as $idx => $subarray) {
    foreach ($subarray as $name => $item) {
        foreach ($item as $names => $items) {
                if ($items == null) unset($arr[$idx]);
        }
    }
}

print_r($arr);
```

Чтобы найти пустой элемент в многомерном массиве, мы просто добавляем еще один foreach чтобы искать внутри еще одного массива, это просто, если же в таком массиве внутри еще один массив, то опять таки добавляем foreach.